# How to subscribe to providers status change events using Fused Location?

Tags: android, android-location, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

Google recommends using `FusedLocationProviderClient` instead of `LocationManager`

Using `LocationManager` I could subscribe to change status events of providers by using `LocationListener` interface:

```
void onProviderEnabled(@NonNull String provider) {}
void onProviderDisabled(@NonNull String provider) {}
```

How can I do it using `FusedLocationProviderClient`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So answer my own question.

For `FusedLocationProviderClient` we use `LocationCallback` in which we have the next method which we can use together with `LocationManager` to get status of providers

```
override fun onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability: LocationAvailability?) {
    super.onLocationAvailability(LocationAvailability)
    val isGpsProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)
    val isNetProviderEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
}
```